# How to apply custom order in Criteria API?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

How to apply such SQL order in Criteria API?

```
order by BB.BUILDING_NUMBER, decode(outBo.TYPE, 
                                                  '9E85B2C7F4450851E053230C350A4C39', 1, 
                                                  '9E85B2C7F4490851E053230C350A4C39', 2, 
                                                  '9E85B2C7F4480851E053230C350A4C39', 3, 
                                                  4), 
                                 to_number(regexp_replace(outBo.BUILD_OBJECT_NUMBER, '\\D', '')), 
                                 outBo.BUILD_OBJECT_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjiwo

Database functions can be called through `criteriaBuilder.function("", args..)`.

Comment: Can you tell me, how to use decode function? What should I pass in args?? And how I can use nested functions to_number(regexp_replace.... ?

Comment: Just nest the expressions. `criteriaBuilder.function("decode", root.type(), criteriaBuilder.literal("9E85B2C7F4450851E053230C350A4C39"), 1, ..)` and `criteriaBuilder.function("to_number", criteriaBuilder.function("regex_replace", root.get("buildObjectNumber"), ..)..`